# How to play video in react.js using html5 video tag?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, video

```
const Video = () => {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <p>hello</p>
      <video width="350" height="350" controls loop autoplay muted>
      <source src="/Videos/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
     </video>
      </div>
    );   
}
export default Video
```

How to play video in reactjs using html5 video tag?
This is how my directory is structured:

Does anyone know why my video does not load? It shows the player but no video.
I tried this as suggested: src="../Videos/video1.mp4" and I get the same result

Comment: Most likely the path you have given isn't correct - which you should be able to easily verify using your browser dev tools.

Comment: Keep video in side public folder the replace path like this "../Videos/myvideo.mp4"
Video path "public/Videos/myvideo.mp4". By default it take public folder so you need to keep all file and folder inside public folder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can show us your project structure, so that we can verify where exactly your video is located,

Also, try putting online video URL, if it works then problem is in your path only.